# How Can I Have A Conditional .htaccess Block?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

This is an Apache question you've probably come across before. I want to have one source package that I can deploy to my workstation, my staging server, and my production server, but for it to load different .htaccess settings based on what the URL was.

Note that I was using a kludge with an IfModule call, but that won't work with our new production server because it shares all the same modules as my staging server.

Note I need to bundle SetEnv with these rewrites. Currently if you use RewriteCond, it only ties to the following RewriteRule, but not the SetEnv underneath.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using SetEnv, use the environment variable setting capabilities of RewriteRule itself:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =foo.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=VARNAME:foo]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =bar.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=VARNAME:bar]
```

Although I prefer doing this sort of thing by passing flags to the httpd process at startup and looking for them using IfDefine blocks.

```
<IfDefine FOO>
SetEnv VARNAME foo
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine BAR>
SetEnv VARNAME bar
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: It should be noted that the php_value directive in Apache cannot be called in the first example -- only environment variables. In the second example, this is the best choice because you can literally define your server. However, this only works if you control the environment. If you are on a shared host, you have no way to control passing a parameter to the httpd process. Therefore, you look for inverse of this with <IfDefine !FOO>.

Comment: I found I can use IfDefine because my prod server is 100% controlled by me and I can mess with the /etc/sysconfig/httpd OPTION parameter and make it OPTIONS="-D prod". On the staging server, which is shared, I had to use IfDefine !prod and then stack an IfModule expires_module underneath it. On my workstation, I had to use IfDefine !prod followed by IfModule !expires_module. This gave me one .htaccess file that worked in dev, staging/test, and production.

Comment: Kinda confusing, made me thought that simple enviroment variables could be used on ifdefine

Comment: RewriteCond is hard to understand. Using a Define is a bit clumsy. I think the better solution would be to use a conditional on the URL or IP address. When I figure out how to do this I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

**On Ubuntu Linux**, the `IfDefine`'s variable is set in

```
/etc/apache2/envvars
```

and is called `APACHE_ARGUMENTS`. So, at the bottom of that file I had to add:

```
export APACHE_ARGUMENTS="-D dev"
```

...and then bounce the server with:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

**On other systems:**

However, there's a Debian article on this topic that discusses this [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=475150). In that example, the file to edit is /etc/default/apache2 and the variable is called `APACHE_DEFINES`.

Likewise, on some systems it is a variable named `OPTIONS` that is set in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`.

So, what you really need to do is look for the start section in your apache2ctl file. So, begin by doing a `whereis apache2ctl` to find where that script is, cat it out and find the start section with the apache2 directive in it, and see if the variable it passes is `OPTIONS`, `APACHE_ARGUMENTS`, `APACHE_DEFINES`, or something else. Then, see which file you need to edit by experimentation with either `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`, `/etc/default/apache2`, or `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the `IfDefine` method and it didn't work, even though the  defined variable i'd passed into the Apache startup was definitely showing up in `phpinfo()` on the `APACHE_ARGUMENTS` line.

I tried another method and it worked perfectly. In your `.htaccess` file you need something like:

`# Is the domain local (i wanted to check two names)?
<If "%{SERVER_NAME} != 'localhost' && %{SERVER_NAME} != 'myproject.localhost'">
    # I wanted to password protect the production server only
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted area"
    AuthUserFile /app/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</If>`

I'm using Apache 2.4. Might not work for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that should be enough for you to change it to meet your requirements:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does that work kind of serially, where I can then append another RewriteCond below it with more RewriteRule entries, and it will only apply to the previous RewriteCond? I mean, in normal programming languages and markup you have some kind of start/stop block, whether it be curly braces. But not here

Comment: Also, is RewriteBase / important?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it only works for RewriteRule, try and also use it for SetEnv or php_value and it doesn't work. That's why I used the IfModule kludge.