# Apache: How to perform a conditional require based on server (.htaccess)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, conditional-statements, require

My Apache is rusty.

If two servers, *foo* and *bar*, use the same *.htaccess* file that restricts users using `require group` or `require user`, how do you base the requirement on the server?  I don't think you use RewriteCond here, but I forget.

---

#### Looking for something like:

```
# if foo.com
require group foo 

# if bar.com
require group bar
```

Comment: This might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736524/how-can-i-have-a-conditional-htaccess-block

Comment: Yeah I already saw that before I posted this.  It's using RewriteCond and RewriteRule, which I thought I already covered by saying `I don't think you use RewriteCond here`.  I think rewrites are handled differently from authentication/permission control.

Comment: there's an `allow from <host>` and `deny from <host>`, but I haven't seen anything like `require group <groupname> from <host>`

Comment: Well, .htaccess and httpd.conf both contain directives that Apache uses to handle both rewrites and permission control. It would of course be possible to configure servers *foo* and *bar* at the httpd.conf level to use different files to control access at the directory level (e.g. .htaccess_foo and .htaccess_bar), but your question is about using the same .htaccess file for both. I'll see if I can generate (or find) an example.

Comment: @Peter: you're exactly right, furthermore, I'd to avoid modifying the httpd.conf and/or restarting apache.  The heart of this problem is that the groups are not the same between servers.  Instead of `foo` and `bar` it'd be better to call that group one universal name on all servers, however, when it comes to practice, idealism takes a back seat. I'll dig into it too, thx for the help

Comment: All the examples I've seen put Require directives inside a <Directory> directive, although it looks like they ought to fit *syntactically* inside a <VirtualHost> directive, which (if it actually worked) might let you do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented here: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/modperl/modperl/93036, I could only find a Mod_Perl alternative, but I don't want to rely on that, should mod_perl be turned off in the future:

```
BEGIN 
{ 
    if (exists $ENV{MOD_PERL}) 
    { 
        require Apache::Constants; 
        import Apache::Constants qw(:common :http); 
    } 
}
```