# Can I use htaccess to prepend a file for specific referring domain

Tags: .htaccess, referrer

I know you can prepend a file via htaccess via:

`php_value auto_prepend_file prepend.php`

I am wondering if it is possible to do so based on a list of referring domains.

So if the referring domain is `domain1.com`, `somedomain2.com`, `whatever3.com`, etc... the file would be prepended.

Thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736524/how-can-i-have-a-conditional-htaccess-block